# Mail server for JavaMail testing

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I want to test JavaMail locally, so I need a mail server. Are there any free mail servers I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sign up for a Gmail account and then use the settings there.  See this page for more details:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

That gives you an SMTP server.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Gmail account for extensive unit testing. Mine got disabled after a while for violating the Google Terms of Service.

Answer (score 21):

There is also very simple in use [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/) which was designed as a mail server for automatic unit (self-integration?) tests.

From projects web page (maybe there are some others tools with that functionality nowadays):

> GreenMail is an open source, intuitive
>   and easy-to-use test suite of email
>   servers for testing purposes. Supports
>   SMTP, POP3, IMAP with SSL socket
>   support. GreenMail also provides a
>   JBoss GreenMail Service.
>
> GreenMail is the fist and only library
>   that offers a test framework for both
>   receiving and retrieving emails from
>   Java.

Comment: Greenmail is great, it lets you easily write unit tests that are very controlled.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: I like the simplicity. It starts all servers with 2 lines of code. smtp 3025
smtps 3465
pop3 3110
pop3s 3995
imap 3143
imaps 3993

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not support the IMAP IDLE command :(

Comment: @BarryNL Did you create an issue for that? https://github.com/greenmail-mail-test/greenmail/issues

Comment: Here's an issue requesting IMAP IDLE: https://github.com/greenmail-mail-test/greenmail/issues/275

Answer (score 10):

Have you looked at [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) ? This is a Java mail server, which means you may be able to run it up temporarily as part of your unit test setup (and obviously take it down afterwards)

Answer (score 7):

I'm after a 'real' test endpoint so will have a look at James, but could do with something a bit more lightweight.

Previously I have used 'Mock JavaMail'  which you drop into your classpath and it works as an in-memory mail store for all accounts & message. https://mock-javamail.dev.java.net/

Comment: Now located here: http://java.net/projects/mock-javamail/

Comment: Mock-JavaMail was a lifesaver for me!

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISP provide you a free mail service? One which only allows sending from one of their IPs?

Don't know what SMTP Auth support is like in JavaMail but you might be able to use gmail's smtp if you have an account.

Answer (score 0):

I like "test mail server tool". It runs on your pc as a mailserver, writes emails out to a folder somewhere and you can set it to popup a window when an email comes in.

http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Answer (score 0):

You can try JavaMail Mock2 https://github.com/salyh/javamail-mock2

Its primarily focused on IMAP/POP3 but SMTP Mock is also available. Its available in maven central.

Features

- Support imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, smtp, smtps
- Supported for POP3: cast to POP3Folder, Folder.getUID(Message msg)
- Supported for IMAP: cast to IMAPFolder, cast to UIDFolder, Subfolders, -Folder.getMessagesByUID(...), delete/rename folders, append messages
- Support for SMTP: Mock Transport.send()
- Unsupported for the moment: IMAP extensions like IDLE, CONDSTORE, ... and casts to POP3Message/IMAPMessage, store listeners